# Laravel, VueJs, Vite - Can't access 'X' before initialization

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vite

Can someone point me in the right direction,

I have a Laravel application that is using VueJs and Vite to compile assets.

On initial serve i.e

```
npm run dev
```

My application works as expected, however, when I make a change to a component I get the following error.

```
client.ts:113 ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Login' before initialization
    at authRoutes.js?t=1663835744201:10:20
```

Here's my authRoutes file.

```
import Login from "@/views/auth/login.vue";
import ForgotPassword from "@/views/auth/forgot-password.vue";
import ResetPassword from "@/views/auth/reset-password.vue";

export default [
    {
        path: "/login",
        name: "Login",
        component: Login,
        meta: { layout: "blank" },
    },
    ...
]
```

This happens with any route after a change to a component as all my components are loaded in the route file like above.

My app.js

```
import "./bootstrap";

import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./app.vue";
import router from "./router/index";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: Where did you add this id = "app"? I think this is because Vite is the problem. Can you run Vue without Vite (for testing)? Or try another version of Vite.

Comment: @MariuszMalek I can confirm the "app" id is associated with the parent div within my app.blade file as usual.

Comment: I read about this and probably this is a Vite issue. Just try to launch without Vite, and after that I can help you better.

Comment: I've had this happen with circular dependencies. Maybe try something like [this](https://github.com/tkskto/vue-component-analyzer)?

Comment: Or use Madge if it's in .js files

Comment: Worked prior to Vite so it is a vite config issue no doubt. I resolved the issue by changing them from imports to const and lazy loading the components.

Comment: @Yitz can you explain the circular dependency problem and how you solved it?

Comment: What @Dev.W means is: { path: '/login', component: () => import('../views/Login.vue') } and remove the import Login from "@/views/auth/login.vue"; That solves the issue.